# How to understand the measurement on entangled state in the following cases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, measurement-problem

Assuming an EPR pair AB, event MA is a measurement on A.

[image]

My questions are:

(1) At MB and MB' (depending on where B is located), if we try to describe the state of B (but not measure B yet), what's the difference between MB and MB'?

(2) If MB and MB' are measurements on B, then what's the influences of the operations MB and MB' on the state of B? It seems that before the measurement on B, MB and MB' are different(depending on different observers?), but after the measurement, are they in the same state?

(3) For MB', it seems that MB' is not determined by MA since they are spacelike separated and there is no definite synchronization. But is the state at MB fully determined by MA?

I am hoping somebody can help to give a complete picture of this problem. There must be somebody has considered this problem through, but I can not find it.

It might seem trivial for some people, but for me I think it's both related with the measurement problem and the relationship between entanglement/spacetime, and some other topics as well.  I do not agree that it should not be discussed. At least for some people it's a question that need to be checked (See the answer of udrv).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33562/discussion-between-curiousone-and-x-dong).

Comment: *See the answer of udrv* Note that answers do *not* make a *question* on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in this review on ["Quantum Information And Relativity Theory"](http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0212023). It isn't very recent anymore, but provides a good grip on the fundamentals.

I am adding some intro. The answer to the questions themselves is at the bottom.

There are two basic concepts that you need to keep in mind relative to quantum measurements:

> M1. Quantum measurements are performed on single systems, but the information they produce makes sense only in the context of a statistical ensemble.

In other words, you always need to repeat *the same measurement* a large number of times on *identically prepared systems* in order to extract definitive information. A single measurement on a single system only provides information on the post-measurement state of the system (we always know what it is with 100% certainty), but generally not on its state  *before the measurement*. For the latter it is necessary to interrogate a large number of identical systems.

> M2. For entangled pairs of quantum systems, as far as *state statistics* is concerned, local measurements on either member of a pair never affect the local state statistics of the other member.

What this means:

Alice and Bob share members of a large number $N$ of identically prepared entangled qubit (or any other quantum system) pairs $\{a_i, b_i\}_{i=1}^N$: Alice keeps qubits $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N\}$, constituting what we may call ensemble A, while Bob gets qubits $\{b_1, b_2, ..., b_N\}$, or ensemble B. Bob carefully moves his qubits at a distant location from Alice. For convenience let each qubit pair be prepared in a state 
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \alpha \;|\phi_a\rangle\otimes|\phi_b\rangle + \beta\; |\psi_a\rangle\otimes|\psi_b\rangle 
$$
where $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ are orthonormal, but otherwise arbitrary single-qubit states, $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle = 0$,$\langle \phi|\phi\rangle = \langle \psi|\psi\rangle = 1$, and $\alpha$, $\beta$ are complex numbers such that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$.

The entangled nature of state $|\Psi\rangle$ means that:

> M1'. If Alice measures qubit $a_i$ and finds it in state $|\phi_a\rangle$ ( $|\psi_a\rangle$ ), then she knows with 100% certainty that when/if Bob measures his corresponding qubit $b_i$ he will find it in state $|\phi_b\rangle$ ( $|\psi_b\rangle$ ). But *before the measurement* Alice has no idea whether she is going to obtain state $|\phi_a\rangle$ or $|\psi_a\rangle$. Likewise, the fact that Alice knows exactly what she obtained in one individual measurement, and also what Bob will obtain in his corresponding measurement, doesn't tell her anything about what she might obtain in her next measurement, on a different qubit. She **cannot reproduce individual outcomes** at will.

In order to determine the state of her qubits, Alice needs to measure her entire ensemble,  or at least a statistically significant subensemble. Such an ensemble measurement tells her that the qubits are each in a mixed state described by a density matrix
$$
\rho_a = Tr_b\left[|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|\right] \;\;(\;= |\alpha|^2 |\phi_a\rangle\langle \phi_a| + |\beta|^2 |\psi_a\rangle\langle \psi_a|\;)
$$
Even so, she only knows that upon a measurement of any one qubit there is a probability $|\alpha|^2$ to obtain $|\phi_a\rangle$ and a probability $|\beta|^2$ to obtain $|\psi_a\rangle$. Nothing more. Similarly for Bob and his qubits. Their density matrix is
$$
\rho_b = Tr_a\left[|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|\right] \;\;(\;= |\alpha|^2 |\phi_b\rangle\langle \phi_b| + |\beta|^2 |\psi_b\rangle\langle \psi_b|\;)
$$

> M2'. Local interactions involving only qubits $a_i$ do not affect the state statistics of qubits $b_i$, and conversely.

*This is the critical part*: No matter what Alice does to her qubits (and only to her qubits), be it measurements or other operations, the state statistics for Bob's qubits does not change. At least not as long as all interactions are completely positive. Say Alice measures all her qubits and keeps track of the results for each one of them. She finds $N|\alpha|^2$ of them in state $|\phi_a\rangle$ and $N|\beta|^2$ in state $|\psi_a\rangle$. She knows *with 100% certainty* what Bob is going to obtain for each of his qubits. But unless she tells Bob about it through other channels, he will not be aware of her measurement results in any way. If he can only rely on his local measurements, all he obtains is that $N|\alpha|^2$ of his qubits are in state $|\phi_b\rangle$ and $N|\beta|^2$ are in state $|\psi_b\rangle$. Alice **cannot change Bob's ensemble statistics**.

**Answer to your question**:
If your event MA refers to a single measurement, on a single qubit (system), then A knows with certainty the outcome at either B or B'. Space-like or time-like separation makes no difference. On the other hand, neither B nor B' have any idea what they might obtain on their side, unless A informs them of his/her result by independent means, and conversely. If A tries to reproduce the first result, s/he finds that it is impossible to control the outcome in order to build a meaningful signal sequence. All that is produced is a random sequence with a statistics determined by the local mixed state.

If your MA is an ensemble measurement, then again A knows with certainty the outcome at either B or B', but the fact that s/he performed a local measurement is never visible in the ensemble statistics of B or B'. The measurement probabilities for various single-system states at B and B' are not affected. Again, space-like or time-like separation are not important.

So, assuming B and B' are stationary wrt A, but acted on at different times so as to obtain time-like or space-like separation:

1) Before measurement each individual system at B or B' would be in a mixed state described by a local (reduced) density matrix. There is no difference between B and B'.

2) The reduced state of an individual system is mixed before the measurement and pure after the measurement. Before the measurement there is an ensemble of $N$ systems each in a mixed state described by a density matrix $\rho_B$. Assuming a complete measurement that accounts for all possible outcomes in some orthonormal basis of pure states $\{|\omega_i\rangle\}$, the state of the ensemble is projected on those pure states. That is, after the measurement there is an ensemble of systems each in some pure state $|\omega_i\rangle$ occurring with a frequency $\langle\omega_i|\rho_B|\omega_i\rangle$, such that overall the ensemble represents a mixed state with density matrix
$$
\bar\rho_B = \sum_i{|\omega_i\rangle\langle\omega_i|\rho_B|\omega_i\rangle\langle\omega_i|}
$$ 
If $\{|\omega_i\rangle\}$ is the eigenbasis of $\rho_B$, then the ensemble statistics is not affected by the measurement.

3) A measurement MA causes the local mixed states of entangled counterparts at B or B' to be reduced to pure states. However, the ensemble statistics embodied by $\rho_B$ (before the B or B' measurement) or $\bar\rho_B$ (after the B / B' measurement) is not affected. The space-like or time-like separation relative to A does not matter. What changes, at most, is the particular realization of the B or B' ensembles: an ensemble of identical individual mixed states (or improper mixtures, as you used in a previous question) before MA vs. a distribution of pure states (a proper mixture) after MA.

**Adding clarifications requested in comments**:

> (1) For MB', can MA turn an improper mixture to a proper mixture? Since MA and MB' are space-like separated, is the conclusion independent of the reference frame? Can we say that before the measurement operation at MB', the state of B at MB' is always an improper mixture?

The standard argument is often that it doesn't matter whether MB' is in a proper or improper mixture once MA is done, on grounds that if ensemble statistics do not change at MB' then no measurement of a standard observable can distinguish whether B's mixed state is a proper or improper mixture.

This being said, if MA destroys entanglement between the $a_i$ and $b_i$ it must transform the overall state of ensembles A and B into a separable state (there are only 2 possibilities: entangled or separable). This applies even if A is left entangled with a measuring device M. In the latter case the overall state would be a separable state of (A+M) and B. Then if MA leaves A (or A+M) as a local probabilistic mixture, the post-measurement separable state of A and B must also be a probabilistic mixture, and by definition it must be realized as a superposition of direct product states of A and B. So B would necessarily be a proper mixture too, regardless of whether MB' is performed or not (*remote preparation*).

The only alternative is that MA leaves pairs $a_i$, $b_i$ in separable states that are not proper mixtures. This would mean that in general a measurement output may be a separable state, but is not necessarily a proper mixture.

The argument seems independent of the space-like or time-like separation of A and B.

> (2) If CTC exists, then after MA, if MB' is in a proper mixture, then CTC can be used to achieve non-local signalling. For example, MA is a projective measurement on either basis {|0>,|1>} or {|+>,|->}, then at MB' CTC can distinguish the non-orthogonal states at MB' and MB' can find out which basis MA used. One way to resolve this is to say after MA, MB' is always an improper mixture so that the CTC can not figure out MA's basis and therefore no signaling. Or someone can just argue 'there is no CTC'.

It doesn't have to be CTCs. According to this very recent article in Nature, it can be causal open timelike curves as well: [Replicating the benefits of Deutschian closed timelike curves without breaking causality](http://www.nature.com/articles/npjqi20157). The result is rather similar. One way or another CTCs and OTCs bring conflict with the no-signaling clause (finite speed of light), the no-cloning theorem, etc. If the argument that MA necessarily causes B to become a proper mixture holds, then it looks like quantum mechanics provides a very good reason why CTCs and OTCs cannot co-exist with the no-signaling clause, regardless of their compatibility with general relativity.

This leaves the issue of whether measurements on entangled pairs $a_i$, $b_i$ produce separable states that are not proper mixtures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer. Still I have a few questions: (1) For MB', can MA turn an improper mixture to a proper mixture? Since there is no synchronization between MA and MB', does the conclusion is reference dependent? Should we say before the measurement operation at MB', the state of B at MB' is always an improper mixture?

Comment: (2) Sorry I have to refer to the closed timelike curve again. If CTC exists, then after MA, if MB' is in a proper mixture, then CTC can be used to achieve non-local signalling. For example, MA is a projective measurement on either basis {|0>,|1>} or {|+>,|->}, then at MB' CTC can distinguish the non-orthogonal states at MB' and MB' can find out which basis MA used. One way to resolve this is to say after MA, MB' is always an improper mixture so that the CTC can not figure out MA's basis and therefore no signaling.  Or someone can just argue 'there is no CTC'. What's your opinion about that?

Comment: It seems that only local measurement on a subsystem turn an improper mixture into a proper mixture (with the ignorance of measurement results). But a remote measurement, in the meaning of space-like separated, will not change the improper mixture. This seems to support Deutsch's idea of the locality of quantum information.

Comment: What I mean is that MA changes MB to a proper mixture, but leave MB' still an improper mixture. After the measurements MB and MB', both of them are proper mixtures. Can this be the case?

Comment: Welcome. (1) Good question, this is a subtle point and the answer is longish, so I added it to the main answer. (2) Not likely that B remains an improper mixture until it becomes time-like separated. See reply in answer as well. And it looks like CTCs are incompatible with no-signaling compliant quantum mechanics.

Comment: About CTC and non-local signaling, since this only happen when MA and MB' are spacelikely separated, then due to the synchronization problem, the existence of non-local signaling is also questionable since it's reference dependent if MB's is sent to a CTC BEFORE or AFTER MA. So lots of contradictions there. That's why I assume that MB' is always an improper mixture to eliminate the paradox. Wish to get your idea. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, typed this a while ago, but didn't post right away. Scrap comment above on (2). There remains the possibility that measurements may produce separable states as improper mixtures, in which case you have a potential point.

Comment: I would like to show my appreciation again for your help and patience. I think I got your idea that in the MA and MB' spacelike separation case, once one of A and B is measured, then both of them become proper mixtures. The reference frame dependent thing is only which one is measured first.

Comment: About the CTC and signaling again, for me the main problem seems not at if the signaling between A and B is against the limited speed of light, but at if the signaling can be achieved is dependent on different observers.  My idea is that if considering the possibility that the entanglement used here violates the spacttime structure, then even the signaling between AB can be achieved, it might not necessarily be 'nonlocal' or 'superluminal'. The reference dependent observations maybe due to measurement problem as we discussed here, or due to the consistency condition of D-CTC itself.

Comment: We keep overlapping :) Re: your comment from 1hr ago: The reason why the standard interpretation relies on proper mixtures at MB' and MB is that correlations and amplitudes must be consistent over series of successive distinct measurements. But it is possible that correlations can be understood identically correct even if measurement outputs are only separable states, but not proper mixtures. So as long as the consistency of various correlations is accounted for, I don't see any harm in assuming measurement outputs as improper mixtures.

Comment: This is why I mentioned in another answer that it would be nice to know if measurements produce proper or improper mixtures. And then there are the paradoxes you mention. Didn't think much about these, but I already have an issue with the idea that an OTC/CTC may bypass the no-cloning theorem. The latter was originally introduced as a response to the observation that universal cloning may enable an ftl protocol (Nick Herbert's protocol). So allowing cloning is guaranteed to bring back the ftl problem, which normally would mean relativistic CTCs are not compatible with relativity...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33665/discussion-between-x-dong-and-udrv).

Comment: Two papers on state cloing with D/P-CTC you may be interested. (1)Perfect state distinguishability and computational speedups with postselected closed timelike curves, arXiv:1008.0433v2 (2)Quantum state cloning using Deutschian closed timelike curves, arXiv:1306.1795v3. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Got them, great!

Comment: @X.Dong Not sure if you noticed, I left a note in Chat 2 days ago. If you already know of it, please ignore this.

Comment: I just received the notification from the system. Thanks a lot for your help. I also posted my understanding and questions in the chat. And I hope I can still discuss with you about it.